# QVector with Qthreads

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, vector

Hello I'm trying to build a `QVector` of `QThread` objects but when I try to build I get this error `'QObject::QObject' : cannot access private member declared in class 'QObject'`. Can someone tell me why I am getting this error and how to over come it or point me in the direction of answer. Thank you for you time.

MAIN.CPP

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include "thread.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>

main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    unsigned long long startingNumberAnswer = 0;
    unsigned long long totalIterationsAnswer = 0;
    int numberOfThreads = 10;


    QVector<Thread> threads(numberOfThreads);

    for(int l = 0; l < threads.size(); l++ ){
        threads[l].setPriority(QThread::TimeCriticalPriority);
    }


    for(int i = 1; i< 2000000; i+=numberOfThreads){
        qDebug() << "Longest iteration Number =  " << startingNumberAnswer;
        qDebug() << "Number of iterations for " << startingNumberAnswer << " is " << totalIterationsAnswer;
        qDebug() << "Running # " << i;


        system("CLS");

    }



    qDebug() << "Longest iteration Number =  " << startingNumberAnswer;
    qDebug() << "Number of iterations for " << startingNumberAnswer << " is " << totalIterationsAnswer;



    return a.exec();
}
```

THREAD.H

```
#ifndef THREAD_H
#define THREAD_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QThread>

class Thread :  public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Thread();

    unsigned long long getloops();
    unsigned long long getnumber();
signals:

public slots:
    void run(unsigned long long value);
private:
    unsigned long long largestNumber;
    unsigned long long loops;
    unsigned long long number;


};

#endif // THREAD_H
```

THREAD.CPP

```
#include "thread.h"

Thread::Thread()
{
}

void Thread::run(unsigned long long value)
{
   unsigned long long n = value;
   unsigned long long counter = 0;

   while ( n > 1){

       if(n%2 == 0){
          n = n/2;
       } else {
          n = (3*n) + 1;
       }

       counter++;
   }

    loops = counter;
    number = value;

}

unsigned long long Thread::getloops(){
    return loops;
}

unsigned long long Thread::getnumber(){
    return number;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, QObject objects are not copyable nor assignable - check the [official documentation](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qobject.html#no-copy-constructor-or-assignment-operator):

> **No copy constructor or assignment operator**
>
> QObject has neither a copy constructor nor an assignment operator.
>   This is by design. Actually, they are declared, but in a private
>   section with the macro Q_DISABLE_COPY(). In fact, all Qt classes
>   derived from QObject (direct or indirect) use this macro to declare
>   their copy constructor and assignment operator to be private. The
>   reasoning is found in the discussion on Identity vs Value on the Qt
>   Object Model page.
>
> The main consequence is that you should use pointers to QObject (or to
>   your QObject subclass) where you might otherwise be tempted to use
>   your QObject subclass as a value. **For example, without a copy
>   constructor, you can't use a subclass of QObject as the value to be
>   stored in one of the container classes. You must store pointers.**

So, you will need to use `QVector<Thread*>` to store threads (don't forget to create objects before using them).

It is also noted in [QVector's documentation](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qvector.html):

> QVector's value type must be an assignable data type. This covers most data types that are commonly used, but the compiler won't let you, for example, store a QWidget as a value; instead, store a QWidget *. A few functions have additional requirements; for example, indexOf() and lastIndexOf() expect the value type to support operator==(). These requirements are documented on a per-function basis.